# "word-wrap" an LI within a UL

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to wrap some text onto the next line that I have held in an LI - the wrapping needs to be done dynamically so I'm looking towards CSS

I want it to look something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li> normal sized </li>
    <li> big massive long one that i'd like to wrap to the next line like below </li>
    <li> the result that
            i'd like to see </li>
</ul>
```

I don't want any scrollbars, and I don't want it to go off the page, and setting the width of either the UL or LI in CSS doesn't seem to be doing it for me. Any ideas? I'm sure its something trivial I'm missing

Thanks

**Edit:** I've tried those solutions without any luck - by themselves, they work fine. So I have to conclude that the problem lies somewhere in the jQuery code I'm using. (using a plugin called jqueryFileTree). The code pulls up a filename, so there's probably a problem there with breaking the line

Comment: Could you give some more context as to what you are experiencing? Browsers, maybe some more code?

Comment: Do you mean to have that indent as well? That's going to be essentially impossible / not x-browser / require JS or extra mark-up if so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting the width on the `ul` element should do the trick. I tried it with your basic example, and it works in FF3, IE 5.5-8.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>test</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            ul {
                width: 80px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li> normal sized </li>
            <li> big massive long one that i'd like to wrap to the next line like below </li>
            <li> the result that i'd like to see </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The text will be wrapped by itself with no CSS applied at all when it reaches the end of the viewport ("viewing area" in the browser) or the end of its elements specified width. This applies to all elements as long as they are not absolutely positioned outside the viewport initially.

I must say I'd like to know how you actually made the text extend beyond the viewport or width of UL/LI.

Answer (score 1):

How are you setting the width on the  element?

The following will not work:

```
<ul width="100">
    <li>Normal Sized</li>
    <li>Big massive long one that I'd like to wrap to the next line</li>
    <li>The result I'd like to see</li>
</ul>
```

You need to set with width either in CSS or in the style property on the tag:

```
<ul style="width: 100px;">
    <li>Normal Sized</li>
    <li>Big massive long one that I'd like to wrap to the next line</li>
    <li>The result I'd like to see</li>
</ul>
```

or you could create a css class rather than setting the width for every ul on the page:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .smallList {
        width: 100px;
    }
</style>

<ul class="smallList">
    <li>Normal Sized</li>
    <li>Big massive long one that I'd like to wrap to the next line</li>
    <li>The result I'd like to see</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm sure you meant .smallList rather than #smallList in your style.